# Correct way to add jQuery plugin with RequireJS

Tags: jquery, requirejs

I want to add a jQuery plugin that vertically align elements within a parent element. In other instances where I was not using RequireJS, I would just write a global function, like so:

```
 (function ($) {
    $.fn.vAlign = function() {
      return this.each(function() {
        var ah = $(this).height();
        var ph = $(this).parent().height();
        var mh = (ph - ah) / 2;
        $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
      });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I can then call that like so: `$('.someclass').vAlign()`. What  I'm trying to understand is how this should be done now that I'm using RequireJS. Do I write a module?

I found a description of writing a module using RequireJS [here](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/07/requirejs-amd-tutorial-introduction/), but it describes a scenario in which you call the function not on an element in the DOM, as you would with jQuery, but by referencing the library name in which you defined the module.

Is there a way to write a module in RequireJS such that the function can be called on an element in the DOM the way you would in jQuery?

Comment: Duplicate of [Can I write a javascript file that optionally uses require.js to specifies dependencies when it is available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351621/can-i-write-a-javascript-file-that-optionally-uses-require-js-to-specifies-depen). Your question is a subset of the question there, and the answer I gave there covers what you need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely you can write a seperate module and load the same when required.

`valign.js` is the module which contains the logic to vertical align elements.

```
//valign.js
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    $.fn.vAlign = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            var ah = $(this).height();
            var ph = $(this).parent().height();
            var mh = (ph - ah) / 2;
            $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
        });
    };
});
```

add `valign.js` module as a dependancy in your `main.js` which call the vertical align code

```
//main.js
define(['jquery','valign'], function($, v) {
   $('.someclass').vAlign(); 
});
```